# TensorflowLite iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I need to run a tensorflow lite model in iOS, from input it receives an array (1, 4500, 1), but I don't understand how to send it to input without transforming it as data.
If I print it out to the Interpreter and the Input tells me exactly what I need, but when I run the code it prints out nil output.
I found this in the internet guides:

```
let resultArray = (
          boundingBox: [Float](unsafeData: outputBoundingBox.data) ??
)
```

But the Float unsafedata function tells me it doesn't exist.
Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import TensorFlowLite
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var opt1 = Interpreter.Options()
        opt1.threadCount = 2
        let model_path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "model1", ofType: "tflite")
        let int1 = try? Interpreter(modelPath: model_path!, options: opt1)
        try? int1?.allocateTensors()

        let input = try? int1?.input(at: 0).shape

        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "numpytest", ofType: "txt") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                let data2 = Data(filepath.utf8)            
                try? int1!.copy(data2, toInputAt: 0)
                try? int1?.invoke()
                let salida = try? int1?.output(at: 0)
            } catch {
                // contents could not be loaded
            }
        } else {
            // example.txt not found!
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, what do I need to add?

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

Greetings!

Comment: In this line: `let data2 = Data(filepath.utf8)`, shouldn't it be `Data(contents)` instead?

Comment: the xcode show this "Missing argument label 'base64Encoded:' in call"
should be like that, "filepath" is the open file with "bundle.main.path", "contents" is simply the contents of the file.